# how to disable workspace higlighter popup during switching workspace

Tags: unity, workspaces, workspace-switcher

How can i disable this small window that's pop-up when i switch workspace in ubunt14.04.
If you did not get it  have uploaded the screen shot over this link.
http://s7.postimg.org/8tvsmbw1n/Screenshot_from_2014_11_14_16_23_57.png which shows popup in between which i want to disable.

thanks alot for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install compizconfig-settings-manager. Open it up, (command ccsm), go to Desktop Wall plugin > disable `Show Viewport Switcher Preview`

[image]